# Increase request queue limit of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, download, iis-8

Not sure if my title is technically correct but I have a problem.

I have a asp.net 4.5 site on IIS 8 and use asp.net to control/limit file downloads. 
Instead of letting IIS to server large (10-20MB) static files such as zip I use asp.net.

It works fine until around 500 to 700 users start downloading. After that asp.net starts to queue all the request to the domain until the active request count goes below some sort of pre determined number.

Static content such as html isn't affected. If I enable more than one worker processes it handles more requests but that brings issue of managing session state.

There is no queue issue if I let IIS serve files. 
Is there any way increasing queue length of asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the request queue limit and the maximum concurrent threads allowed per CPU

```
<system.web> 
  <applicationPool 
       maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="12" 
       maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" 
       requestQueueLimit="5000"/> 
</system.web>
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/07/08/iis7-improving-asp-net-performance-concurrent-requests-while-on-integrated-mode.aspx

However, I would suggest serving larger static files via a CDN if that is possible in your situation.  The default limits are in place for a reason.  If you lift the configured values too far above the defaults, you may start to experience performance issues and runtime errors.

Amazon's S3 CDN (and probably other CDN's) provide a range of options to control access to files on the CDN

> enables you to leverage the fine grained access control that IAM User policies provides while also reducing your exposure by enabling you to further restrict and limit the request to a predefined time for each one of your users.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5050/

Comment: thanks, I will modify and apply above to my web.config to see if it will help. CDN out of picture for me. Site is just a personal site and bandwidth it consumes would be very very expensive on CDN

Comment: oh, it is for Aspnet.config

Comment: In that case you might consider writing an HTTP handler that simply checks for any necessary conditions (e.g. user is logged in) and then serves the file statically.  That would remove the ASP.Net processing overhead.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sorry to be pain, I am not trying to dispute your replies. I have already done that but people clever to get hold of actual location and use my site to hot link :)

Comment: Anything you can do in an ASP.Net page, you should be able to do in an HTTP handler.  Just that you do not have the ASP.Net page semantics.  You can check the referrer, you can set a "user valid" cookie and check that in the HTTP handler.