# WCF service call getting queued. Sometimes returning a 500 internal server error

Tags: performance, wcf, .net-4.5, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a WCF (.NET 4.5.2) application hosted on IIS 8.5 Windows 2012 R2 machine which calls to another WCF (.NET 4.5.2)  application hosted on another IIS 8.5 Windows 2012 R2 machine. Problem is that when there are bulk calls (Let say 200+) my requests seems to be queuing.

Any idea what particular improvement I do? Both Machines have 4 cores and 4 GB ram

At the moment I have tried with following tweak in machine config

```
<!-- <processModel autoConfig="true" /> -->
    <processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="1400" maxIoThreads="1400" minWorkerThreads="10" />
```

One problem i also see randomly is that I get 500 internal error. Looks like calls never reaches the second server.
Full error trace is

```
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 192 bytes of the response were: '<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
'.
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 192 bytes of the response were: '<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: [You could make your WCF service async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx) and benefit from IOCP

Comment: That's the architecture change which we can't afford at the moment. We also have planed to move from soap based service to restful one but at the moment i am looking get maximum performance with current application via possible any configuration tweak

Comment: Perhaps.  It's much easier to add a `Task<>` prefix (and a few bits and pieces) to your WCF methods than to re-write everything as REST.  Wishing you well

Comment: Yep.But not at the moment. I have just able to upgrade my application from .net 3.5 to 4.5.2 and Move it from old windows 2008 server to windows 2012 R2 server. Will do those application level changes later

Comment: Sounds like a queue limit.  Check out [Increase request queue limit of asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729682/increase-request-queue-limit-of-asp-net) on IIS8

Comment: I think this is the same limit which we can see via Application Pool -> MyPool->Advanced settings -> QueueLength. Mine is currently set to 1000. which i thought is quite enough.now set it to 3000

Comment: Quite possibly.  You could benefit from this non-code-change however take note of the warnings in the link.  It may only delay the inevitable hence the `async` suggestion.

Comment: _[If you lift the configured values too far above the defaults, you may start to experience **performance issues** and runtime errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729682/increase-request-queue-limit-of-asp-net)_

Comment: Micky Can you confirm the processMode related configuration change i am trying is worth while considering i have windows 2012 r2 server with .net 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log4net db logging was found to be the culprit. DB logging was happening one by one so I have increased the bufferSize property of log4net to 10.